# .NET 6 Identity Server cannot store user tokens

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I am implementing Identity Server on my .NET 6 project. And I want to store refresh tokens on my database. But these lines of code that I've found in StackOverflow ([Using AspNetUserTokens table to store refresh token in ASP.NET Core Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659247/using-aspnetusertokens-table-to-store-refresh-token-in-asp-net-core-web-api)) store tokens in memory instead of AspNetUserTokens table. How can I persist my tokens?

```cs
services
    .AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
    .AddTokenProvider("MyApp", typeof(DataProtectorTokenProvider<MyUser>));
```

And I call UserManager

```cs
var newRefreshToken = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, "MyApp", "RefreshToken");
await _userManager.SetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "MyApp", "RefreshToken", newRefreshToken);
```

I can get the token when I call `GetAuthenticationTokenAsync` but cannot display on the database.

```cs
var token = await _userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "MyApp", "RefreshToken");
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter this problem, I share the solution that I found on Github (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35656). Basically, I moved order of DBContext registration from this:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IMyDbContext, MyDbContext>();
services.AddScoped(MySecondDbContext);
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
```

to this:

```cs
services.AddScoped(MySecondDbContext);
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
services.AddScoped<IMyDbContext, MyDbContext>();
```

And problem solved. I can save my tokens on the database now.